# Logging in ASP.NET MVC 5 .NET Standard Framework 4.7.1 (NOT .NET CORE)

Tags: logging, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I enable logging in my ASP.NET MVC 5 Application ?

ASP.NET MVC 5 .NET Standard Framework 4.7.1 (NOT .NET CORE)

I created a new project in Visual Studio 2017 but it does not add any logging.

Most of the help in the Internet and even in ASP.NET website, shows only .NET Core 2 Logging and nothing for the .NET Standard.

Please advise.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

[log4net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/) is probably the most popular NuGet package for adding logging to a .NET application. It's efficient and easy to use. It allows you to log to a database or to a local file (or to a ton of other options; you can check them all out [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html)).

`log4net` comes with various logging levels, such as ERROR, WARNING, INFO, and DEBUG, which can be useful when reviewing your log files.

I most commonly use the `RollingFileAppender` configuration option. This option creates a new log file per interval (e.g. day) and keeps log files on a rolling interval basis (e.g. 30 days).

```
<log4net debug="true">
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="C:\\your\\path\\" />
  <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyyMMdd'.txt'" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
</root>
</log4net>
```

Your preferred configuration may be different based on your own use cases, but I've had nothing but good experiences using `log4net`.

Comment: I am trying to use Microsoft ILogger. Any samples on how to initialize this and use it ?

Comment: Sorry, just log4net.